# Run-Time Error 1004 but Procedure Still Runs

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have an odd issue with a macro triggering a Run-Time Error 1004 message.  The macro does the following:

1. Creates a new worksheet to capture a new project idea (gathers data from a UserForm)
2. Creates a new row on a summary worksheet for that idea
3. Defines a named range (named "IdeaTitles") that holds all of the idea titles from all of the submitted ideas for use in other parts of the workbook (validation lists and such)
4. Displays a confirmation MsgBox to the user

When I run this macro on my machine (in USA), it works flawlessly--no error messages or issues.  When a coworker in Germany runs the macro on his machine, he encounters the following error message:

> Run-time error '1004'

If he clicks the Debug button, it highlights this row of the procedure:

```
wbHopper.Names.Add Name:="IdeaTitles", RefersTo:="=OFFSET('" & wsSummary.Name & "'!$C$6,0,0," & lngCurrentIdeaRow - lngFirstIdeaRow + 1 & ",1)"
```

I had him hover his mouse over each of the variables / objects in that line and they all have reasonable values.  For the first idea, lngCurrentIdeaRow = 6 and lngFirstIdeaRow = 6, which gets you this:

[image: Named Range Formula]

Note that row 6 is the first row in which idea details are stored on the summary sheet.

What's interesting is that if he hits F8 in the Debug window to step through the code, it will complete without any errors.  Thinking I was crazy, I asked him to submit several dummy ideas where he would click "Debug" then hit F5 to finish running the code and it works without error.

Any idea on what might be triggering this error pop-up on his end?  It's not inhibiting the macro from completing, but I'd like to clean that up before he shares it with his team.

Comment: Some regional settings issue involving the commas?

Comment: Like Coleman said, some non-English EXCEL use semi-colon ";" instead of comma.

Comment: Get the correct separator to use with `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`

Comment: Hmm that's a novel thought--I guess I assumed that using commas in formulas was standard regardless of region.  I'll try your suggestion @Mat'sMug

Comment: Excel uses the *list separator* character to separate function arguments. See above comment.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Wouldn't you have to use `RefersToLocal` if you were using locale-specific settings?  (So, just as all users have to use commas in `Formula` but not in `FormulaLocal`, I would have expected they would have to use commas in `RefersTo` and only use semi-colons, etc, in `RefersToLocal`.)

Comment: @YowE3K ugh. worth testing. I need to setup a French-locale VM...

Comment: @Mat'sMug Glad you can do that sort of thing.  I'm stuck with the single language I have, and have to guess every time one of these international-use problems is mentioned.

Comment: Also, "What's interesting is that if he hits F8 in the Debug window to step through the code, it will complete without any errors." implies that it isn't an error due to locale - that usually means it is something wrong with which workbook and or worksheet is active (although I can't see anything wrong with the way the code is written which would cause that)

Comment: So I replaced all of the commas in the "RefersTo" portion with "Application.International(xlListSeparator)" and it seems to have worked perfectly.  Co-worker in Germany confirmed this morning that the error is no longer coming up!  It's surprising to me for sure, but thanks to everyone for helping me track down the issue.

Comment: @Mat'sMug could you post your suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it completed?  Additional thanks to MrDogme and John Coleman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel uses the *list separator* character to separate function arguments.

You can get that character from the system locale settings, using `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`.